# Can pure-blooded Sith breed with Cathars?

Tags: star-wars

I have an idea bouncing around in my head but I wish to find out if the bloodline combination is even possible. the child would be the offspring of a Cathar Jedi and a pureblood Sith who is a Sith warrior. What I would like to know is if that is even possible for the two races to interbreed?

Answer (score 1):

There is no indication on [Wookieepedia](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Cathar_(species)) that Cathar and Sith, or Cathar and *any* other species for that matter, could interbreed. However, since the article references that Cathar biology is similar to that of [Bothans](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Bothan/Legends#Biology_and_appearance), and since Bothans are confirmed to be able to interbreed with some other species, it is *possible* (but not definite) that a Cathar and a Sith would be compatible on a genetic level.

[Sith](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Sith_(species)#Hybridization) are confirmed to be able to interbreed with Humans, although that may require some amount of scientific or Sith alchemical assistance to achieve offspring. It is *possible* that a certain [Half-Bothan](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Half-Bothan#Behind_the_scenes) species was created through such Sith alchemy and interbreeding, so that's a suggestion for your idea.

Comment: In SWTOR it's said that not only *can* sith and humans interbreed, by that time almost all "pureblood" sith are essentially all human with a little sith heritage.